# How can I make website with CRUDBooster and Laravel working?

Tags: laravel, crudbooster

Website based on CRUDBooster and Laravel not working

Tried to change permissions to main directory -r 777

> (1/1) UnexpectedValueException The stream or file
>   "/var/www/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to
>   open stream: Permission denied

I'm having this error when I'm trying to access website build with CRUDBooster and Laravel. Already tried to change permissions to 775 and 777 to all folders and subfolders inside  but still same error.
Any idea?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: are your files located in the root directory?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give right permissions to storage and bootstrap/cache folders (`sudo chmod -R 775 storage` and `sudo chmod -R 775 bootstrap/cache`) and give right group permission to project folder (`sudo chown -R $USER:www-data projectFolder`). This last one (group permission) is for `Apache` server7

Comment: hey, thanks for you reply. is not that. is just the path of the project. for some reason works only if the path have same structure as initial was created. for instance: web/site/project works but when i change it to web/site-b/project not working